# Combine pandas dataframes (triangles rasterization)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, raster

I am trying to rasterize a certain h5 dataset referred to a triangular mesh. I want to avoid using QGIS because loading the results is way to time consuming, so I am trying to achieve that with python.

I import the values as a numpy array and convert it to pandas dataframe as follows

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

f = h5py.File(os.path.join(path,file),'r')
DF5Obj = f['path/to/values/inside/h5/organizer']
Array = np.array(DF5Obj['some_index'])
df_Var = pd.DataFrame(Array)
```

The result is a one-column pandas dataframe.

Then, from the sam h5 file, I import the triangles geometry as follows:

```
df_CellsAll = pd.DataFrame(np.array(f['/CellsAll/Topology/']))
df_CellsAll.columns = ['V1','V2','V3']
df_NodesAll = pd.DataFrame(np.array(f['/NodesAll/Coordnts/']))
df_NodesAll.columns = ['X','Y','Z']
```

The resulting dataframes are reported hereafter.

`df_CellsAll` contains the vertices i.e., the IDs of the points, composing the triangle (1 row = 1 triangle)

```
           V1      V2      V3
0        3074   11298    2755
1       22113   19404    2938
2        2893   20785   13879
3       20472   21061   21064
4        2846    2768   11299
...       ...     ...     ...
349018  60356  175663  175664
349019  60392   68597  175665
349020  68597   61994  175665
349021  84310   76828  175666
349022  76828   86305  175666
```

and `df_NodesAll` contains the coordinates of the point (1 row = 1 point)

```
                    X             Y           Z
0       730276.367143  5.088697e+06  305.546265
1       730275.790000  5.088697e+06  305.191101
2       730058.090233  5.088762e+06  271.104492
3       730049.725534  5.088758e+06  270.111938
4       729794.066720  5.088584e+06  228.502640
...               ...           ...         ...
175662  730145.876109  5.088131e+06  293.498749
175663  729111.338338  5.088125e+06  179.040268
175664  729110.993515  5.088128e+06  178.975510
175665  729877.943429  5.088636e+06  241.432709
175666  730142.940335  5.088687e+06  286.965424
```

What I am trying to do is to combine `df_CellsAll` and `df_NodesAll` to generate a new DataFrame (`df_Triangles`), which is similar to df_CellsAll, but that contains the (X,Y) coordinates of each vertex.

What is the best way to `join` or `merge` two pandas dataframes this way? I can iterate through the dataframe rows, something like:

```
list_Triangles = []
    for index,row in df_CellsAll.iterrows():
    V1_id = row['V1']
    V2_id = row['V2']
    V3_id = row['V3']
    x1 = df_NodesAll['X'][V1_id]
    y1 = df_NodesAll['Y'][V1_id]
    x2 = df_NodesAll['X'][V2_id]
    y2 = df_NodesAll['Y'][V2_id]
    x3 = df_NodesAll['X'][V3_id]
    y3 = df_NodesAll['Y'][V3_id]
    xc = (x1+x2+x3)/3
    yc = (y1+y2+y3)/3
    v = df_v['h'][index]
    list_Triangles.append([x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,xc,yc,v])
df_Triangles = pd.DataFrame(list_Triangles)
```

`df_Triangles` would be something like

```
                   X1            Y1             X2            Y2             X3            Y3             Xc            Yc         h
0       728814.727902  5.088555e+06  728814.652925  5.088555e+06  728815.185125  5.088555e+06  728814.855317  5.088555e+06  0.823227
1       728868.424985  5.089283e+06  728865.887316  5.089281e+06  728867.886914  5.089281e+06  728867.399738  5.089282e+06  1.321808
2       729062.648982  5.089342e+06  729063.254216  5.089341e+06  729063.271655  5.089343e+06  729063.058284  5.089342e+06  1.741959
3       729375.120187  5.089690e+06  729374.243480  5.089689e+06  729375.234723  5.089688e+06  729374.866130  5.089689e+06  0.824570
4       729274.673027  5.088725e+06  729273.781884  5.088725e+06  729274.298439  5.088725e+06  729274.251117  5.088725e+06  0.000000
...               ...           ...            ...           ...            ...           ...            ...           ...       ...
349018  729109.235944  5.088126e+06  729111.338338  5.088125e+06  729110.993515  5.088128e+06  729110.522599  5.088126e+06  0.214249
349019  729879.892656  5.088637e+06  729875.850886  5.088637e+06  729877.943429  5.088636e+06  729877.895657  5.088636e+06  0.000000
349020  729875.850886  5.088637e+06  729878.160775  5.088633e+06  729877.943429  5.088636e+06  729877.318364  5.088635e+06  0.000000
349021  730142.375483  5.088685e+06  730144.903363  5.088688e+06  730142.940335  5.088687e+06  730143.406394  5.088687e+06  0.000000
349022  730144.903363  5.088688e+06  730141.477032  5.088689e+06  730142.940335  5.088687e+06  730143.106910  5.088688e+06  0.000000
```

using `df_Triangles['V1'] = list(zip(df.X1,df.Y1))` and so on, I can generate aggregate columns and obtain something that looks like:

```
                                            V1  ...         h
0       (728814.7279022894, 5088555.119397357)  ...  0.823227
1       (728868.4249850488, 5089282.864303691)  ...  1.321808
2         (729062.648982357, 5089342.00779639)  ...  1.741959
3       (729375.1201870635, 5089689.746423756)  ...  0.824570
4       (729274.6730269277, 5088725.122156201)  ...  0.000000
...                                        ...  ...       ...
349018  (729109.2359440885, 5088125.541482763)  ...  0.214249
349019   (729879.892656163, 5088636.927554153)  ...  0.000000
349020  (729875.8508864521, 5088636.673328585)  ...  0.000000
349021  (730142.3754832243, 5088685.208429256)  ...  0.000000
349022  (730144.9033627728, 5088687.636598083)  ...  0.000000
```

but is there a way to do that more efficiently, or am I facing a problem where iteration cannot be avoided?

**MORE CONTEXT TO MY QUESTION:**

The reason why I am doing this is because I would like to create a raster and to interpolate the values for each pixel from the values contained in the resulting df. It could be that a triangle contains more than 1 pixel, so my idea is to:

1. define the centroids coordinates for each row in my new df;
2. assign to the centroid the value of the variable I want to use for the raster (just appending the `df_Var` df to the new one);
3. build an empty raster based on the coordinates of the vertices and the pixel size
4. interpolate the values of the empty raster with an algorythm (IDW, TIN, Kriging...) using the values of the centroids.

If anyone thinks that there is a better way to interpolate a raster from h5 files, I would be happy to receive any suggestion.

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: Can you not use the `+` operator to add them together?

Comment: @brodegon I think this question is just a little complicated and therefore hard to answer. Before the edits, it definitely did look like you were asking for someone to just write your code for you. I think it would make it easier to answer if you included a mock-up of your desired output, rather than just a text description of it. That makes it much easier for people to figure out what you want.

Comment: I am working on it, providing the idea of code i would use if i was to iterate over the df, and also the expected results

Comment: @Shmack unfortunately the outcome is not what I expect.